# UnboundLocalError 'referenced before assignment' when trying to solve an implicit equation

Tags: python, equation

I get an error when trying to solve this implicit equation:

```
y = x^3 +sqrt(y)
```

Question: Find `y` when `x = [0, 1, 2.5, 2.8, 3, 3.2]`.

> "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'y' referenced before assignment"

How do I solve this:

```
from math import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

def f(x):
    y = np.power(x,3.0) - sqrt(y)
    return y

x = [0, 1, 2.3611, 2.9033, 3.2859, 3.5915]
x= fsolve(f, 0)

print(x)
```

Comment: `y = np.power(x,3.0) - sqrt(y)` but `y` is not defined anywhere prior, so what does `sqrt(y)` evaluate to?

Comment: What roganjosh is pointing at is that you attempt to use y in your equation before it even has a value. One of the answers pointed out that you can refactor your equation so that y is only on the left side, then run your program.

Comment: It's an implicit equation so I guess we are supposed to input different values of x and determine what y is in that equation. Do you have any idea how to approach it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having:

```
y = np.power(x,3.0) - sqrt(y)
```

You can try:

```
y = np.power(x,3.0)
y = y - sqrt(y)
```

The variable y does not exist while you are declaring it

Comment: Please the code works for just the first value of x. Can you help with making the code solve for all the values of x in the question? To find all the other values of y.